# Cannot combine typescript types

Tags: typescript

#### Background

How do you create a type definition that's the combination of these two types?

```
type BlogPost = {
    title: string
    image: {
        src: string
        width: number
        height: number
    }
    content: string
}

type BlogPostDetails {
    [detail: string]: string
}
```

In other words, blog posts should have a title, image, and content, then it could have any other details that are strings.

#### Error

However, any way I've thought of combining them produces an error.

```
Property 'image' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'image' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

For instance, I've tried these:

```
type Post = BlogPost & BlogPostDetails

type Post = BlogPost & Record<string, string>

type Post = {
    title: string
    image: {
        src: string
        width: number
        height: number
    }
    content: string
    [detail: string]: string
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlogPostDetails` insists that all properties with a string name have a string value - this doesn't sit happily with `BlogPost`, which must always have an image property with an object value.

One of them has to change to avoid this conflict.

Luckily, Typescript is great at whittling down types to suit various situations, and comes with some pretty handy helper type functions too. One of these is `Omit<T, K>`, which can be used like so to filter out arbitrary properties from `BlogPostDetails`:

```js
type Post = BlogPost & Omit<BlogPostDetails, 'image'>
```

More info here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys